# Mysql - Select rows created 1 hour ago

Tags: mysql

I try to developp a cron task (PHP-MYSQL) that will be executed every 10 minutes to send an email only on the results of my query.

On this script, i would like to select the rows created 1 hour ago. I have a datetime field which contains the creation date.

How to select rows created 1 hour ago ? (without to take care of minutes and seconds)

I tried this code below but it returns me all the rows older than 1 hour, which is not what i need

```
SELECT email FROM clients WHERE (date_creation  < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR))
```

Comment: What means "1 hour ago"? For example, if you run cron script at 9:30, should it select row created at 8:50 or exactly at 8:30?

Answer (score 5):

You can use this query.

```
SELECT email FROM clients WHERE date_creation >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

it will give you all records created in hour.

Comment: I think it will be `-1 HOUR`, as the user wants to get "Past" hour

Comment: @AmitabhDas -1 HOUR will add 1 HOUR to my time. so it cannot be used.

Comment: thank you but here is the result : 2019-06-05 17:16:29 and i launched the query at 17:22:00 , so it gives me a row created 15 minutes ago